# Android SpeechRecognizer set recognize engine?

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm using SpeechRecognizer to convert speech to text. I'm using Samsung and I encounterd error while I set Voice recognizer to 'Samsung powered by Vlingo', after I changed to 'Google' and the error disappear. I was wondering is there any method to change recognize engine programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: I never tried changing SpeechRecognizer Engine, but what is the error you're getting in Logcat ? Could you please mention that.

Comment: @shree202 I encounterd 'not connected to the recognition service' error while I was using 'Samsung powered by Vlingo' and after I change to 'Google' it disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found the answer of my question. I can use 'public static SpeechRecognizer createSpeechRecognizer (Context context, ComponentName serviceComponent)' the method to choose which recognition service to bind.

Here is the implementation.

```
SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(mContext, ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService"));
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi, If I wanted to set my own speech recognition engine, how can I do that? Is there any sort of format dependencies?

Comment: Does anybody know the Samsung SpeechRecognitionService string?

Comment: You can probably find the details about the available recognition service using:
context.getPackageManager().queryIntentServices(                      Intent(RecognitionService.SERVICE_INTERFACE), 0)