# Is there any ways to use own speech recognition engine with android.speech module?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have implemented a demo speech recognition service my own. I deployed it on a server. Now I can access the service by using an API (*http://192.168.1.100/ASR/demoSpeechToText*). I am passing audio file in *wav* format and  *language* parameter to the API. The API is working fine.

I wanted to integrate this with an Android application. I implemented it as a simple API call from the app which will be called after recording a voice sample.

I wanted to explore further to check the possibility of integrating it with the **android.speech** module (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html).

So my question is, Is there any way that I can extend some classes from ***audio.speech*** module and write my own class to call my speech recognition API than the default one? I have seen this one: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html, but don't know if possible to use with my own API.

Comment: You need to expose it as a `RecognitionService` which you can then bind to using `SpeechRecognizer` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService.html

Answer (score 1):

A very minimal extension of `RecognitionService` is e.g. https://github.com/Kaljurand/speechdemo1 (simply shows which classes need to be extended, does not actually do any recording/recognizing), a more complete one is https://github.com/Kaljurand/K6nele (records audio and streams it to an existing cloud service, but does not support wav-files).

Comment: Let me try this one.

Comment: For changing the recognise engine, I found this solution: **SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(mContext, ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService"));** Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350825/android-speechrecognizer-set-recognize-engine

Here, my question is, I want to replace **"com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.voicesearch.serviceapi.GoogleRecognitionService"** to my own package name. But I don't have any clues on how to write the class.

Comment: The structure of the package/class is unknown to me. In simple terms, using the google recording interface, I want to record voice but the voice will be given to my API instead of Google.

Comment: In **K6nele**, I found two methods. One is using google recorder & google speech to text, and the other is using your own recorder and your own API. As per my requirement, I wanted to use google recorder  clubbed with my API.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use "google recorder", and what is it at all... At the API level there is no separation of recording and recognizing. The client calls `startListening` and starts receiving the transcription via a callback. When `startListening` is called, then the service needs to start recording the audio (using `AudioRecord`), transcribing it (possibly using a cloud service), and returning the transcription and other data via the callbacks.